# QGIS Mask - Error Code

Tags: qgis, interpolation, extract, extract-by-mask

I am trying to interpolate points and then clip the interpolation with a Raster> Extraction> Clipper. I receive an error code after trying to mask over the region I am interested in. Would you possibly know what the error code means?

It says `Ring Self Intersection at or near point`. I tried to break it down to smaller chunks, but I get the same error code.

```
Warning 1: Ring Self-intersection at or near point -53.756366999999955 48.50326200000012
ERROR 1: Cutline polygon is invalid.
```

[image][image: Points I am interpolating][image: My results on the right.]

Fixed the geometry with a the polygon validator. The interpolation is still a little funny (image on the right is what I have. Image on the left is what I want to achieve)

Additional Images and link to tutorial: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/interpolating_point_data.html

[image: Setting for mask]
[image: Setting for contour]

Update after follow Kanban's recommendation to make the resolution smaller. Resolution was set to .2 in the interpolation process.

[image: You can see USA]

Comment: Try repairing/fixing the geometries. In QGIS3 you have the Fix geometries tool, dont know if this is available in 2.18, if not: https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_geometry_checker.html

Answer (score 1):

Not working in this case, see BERA's comment. Answer keeped in case it is useful for someone

---

It looks like your geometry might be malformed.

In order to verify that, you can create a buffer of your mask layer. The distance does not have to be huge, 1m is enough.

Hopefully this will discard any self-intersection by creating 2 distinct rings, allowing you to extract your region of interest.

The error code means that somewhere, one of your rings (holes in the polygons) is cutting its owned border, or has an 8 shape, the center of the 8 being the self intersection. If your data comes from a vectorised raster, it is pretty common, and quite annoying as you may have lots of these. Hence the buffer quick fix to see if this is the real issue or if there is another issue with your data.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the shape file online. I tried the buffer, but that did not work. I was able to use the validator input from QGIS to separate the bad polygons after and clip it from that polygon. The interpolation looks a little strange still.

Comment: Which tool are you using to interpolate? I think that it would be another question. However, you can put the link in the comment, I'll try to have a look. Please describe the tool you've been using as well as your parameters.

Comment: I am using this tutorial: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/interpolating_point_data.html

Comment: I am not sure if it's because I am using 15 points that sit within the boundary to calculate the interpolation. The tutorial uses the edge boundaries (It looks like)-- I figured the mask would cut off any excess/stretch the interpolation to its extents. As for mask. I am using Ratster > Extraction > Clipper. In that pop up, I select mask layer. I included some more image in the question.

Comment: I feel like your grid size is way too coarse. Try using a thinner resolution. Moreover, it looks like your grid is not squared, which is not an issue per se but might make your grid unreadable depending on the softwares that might read it afterwards.

Comment: So I changed the output res to .2, and the result is finer. You can make out US from the interpolation. The interpolation is set to linear (not exact). -- What does it mean for the grid to not be "squared".

Comment: The size of an element of the raster is not the same x and y wise. If you go to Layer properties -> informations -> pixel size, both values should be equal. It seems that it's not the case for you, at least in the first attempt. In the second one, the grid is too thin to be sure.

Comment: You are correct. Turns out the pixel is (0.2,-0.2)

Comment: well if the difference is only the sign, there is nothing to worry about. However, it is expressed in the units of your CRS, so make sure it is the size you are expecting. My guess is that your CRS is based on angles, so that would be 0.2 degrees.

Comment: In that case, interpolating the points to smaller degrees would help with the edge condition then?

Comment: As always, the smaller your resolution, the better the shape will be approximated (see the evolution between your two first attempts). However, the size of your files increases with a power 2. (a file with a resolution 3x thinner will be 9 times bigger)